# continuity on product topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Question:
>   Let $f: X\rightarrow Y$ and $g: X\rightarrow Z$
>   be continuous, where X,Y Z are topological spaces.
>
> Define 
>   $h: X \rightarrow Y \times Z$
>
> $x  \mapsto \left ( f\left ( x \right ),g\left ( x \right ) \right )=h\left ( x \right )$
>   for all $x \in X$
>
> Prove that h is continuous wrt the product topology on $Y \times X$.

Attempt:

Let $\jmath$ ,$\imath$  and $\Im$ be topologies on X, Y and Z, respectively.

f and g are continuous function so by definition of continuous function on a topological space,
we expect:

$\forall u \in \imath: f^{-1}\left ( u \right ) \in \jmath$

$\forall \bar{z} \in \Im: g^{-1}\left ( \bar{z} \right ) \in \jmath$

Clearly, what I do need to show is that the pre-image of the open set in the product topology $\imath  \times  \jmath$ is mapped to an open set in $\jmath$

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do open sets in $Y\times Z$ look like? They are of the form $U\times V$ where $U$ is open in $Y$ and $V$ is open in $Z$. Then you should try to show that

$$h^{-1}(U\times V)=f^{-1}(U)\cap g^{-1}(V)$$

which is open in $X$ by continuity of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: How did the intersection come about? Does it follow from an identity in set theory?

Comment: @Mathematicing $x\in h^{-1}(U\times V)\iff h(x)=(f(x),g(x))\in U\times V\iff f(x)\in U\wedge g(x)\in V\iff x\in f^{-1}(U)\wedge x\in g^{-1}(V)\iff x\in f^{-1}(U)\cap g^{-1}(V)$

Comment: @drhab Much appreciation